# PayPal Express Checkout Validating Payment

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

How can we validate a payment Success/failure using response Token from Paypal in PayPal Express Check Out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DoExpressCheckoutPayment response (if Successful) will include a PAYMENTINFO_n_PAYMENTSTATUS parameter that you can check to see if the payment associated with the API call is actually completed or not.

If this param has a value of "Completed" then you know you're good to go.  It could be "Pending", though, in cases where an e-check is used for payment, fraud filters flag the transaction, etc.

Because of this it is recommended that you use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) in order to handle all post-transaction processing tasks like updating your database, sending email notifications, etc.

Comment: thanks Andrew, DoExpressCheckoutPayment is for committing the transaction.If we supply token which is already committed again to this method we get exception.i.e.this is because i am creating invoice with cart details&token before redirecting to Paypal after success payment  I am updating invoice as "Paid".For some reasons I am unable to update Invoice after successful payment how can i get details of transaction with token i have

Answer (score 1):

PayPal responds with a message, such as the one shown below. Note the status, which should include `ACK` set to `Success`, and a token that is used in subsequent steps.

```
TIMESTAMP=2007%2d04%2d05T23%3a23%3a07Z
&CORRELATIONID=63cdac0b67b50

&ACK=Success

&VERSION=XX%2e000000
&BUILD=1%2e0006
&TOKEN=EC%2d1NK66318YB717835M
```

[Source](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/)